# Probability derivation using axioms

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

$$P((A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B))=P(A) + P(B) -2P(A \cap B).$$

I need to show this holds.
I see it with Venn diagrams but I need to show it using only the axiom, for the union of two disjoint sets:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B).$$

I know the first step is:

$$P((A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)) = P((A \cap B^c))+ P((A^c \cap B)),$$

since these sets are disjoint.
Then I think the next step is to write $A$ as $A = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)$ and $B = (B \cap A^c) \cup (B \cap A)$.

These sets are disjoint.
Then I get:

\begin{multline*}
P((A \cap B^c))+ P((A^c \cap B)) = \\
= P\{[(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)] \cap B^c)\}+ P ((A^c \cap [(B \cap A^c) \cup (B \cap A)]).
\end{multline*}

But I don't know what to do from there.
Thanks.

The statement I'm trying to prove is right here is an image of the answer in the book [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ0fV.png)

Comment: In the final term on the right-hand side of what you're trying to prove, it should be $P(A\cap B)$, not $P(A\cap B^c)$.  And in your decomposition of $A$, the second term should be $A\cap B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second step, you don't want to plug the decompositions of $A$ and $B$ directly into your equation.  Instead, you want to take the equation $P(A)=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A\cap B)$ (which you get directly from $A=(A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap B)$ since the two sets are disjoint) and rearrange it to get $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$, and then plug this expression for $P(A\cap B^c)$ into your equation.  This gives you $$P((A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)) = P(A \cap B^c)+ P(A^c \cap B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B).$$

Similarly, $P(A^c\cap B)=P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, so you get $$P((A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B))=P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B).$$

Answer (score 1):

So you are correct in stating that $(A\cap B^c)$ and $(A^c\cap B)$ are disjoint. This is obvious because $(A\cap B^c)\cap(A^c\cap B)=\{0\}$

By the properties of probability,
$P(X\cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$.

So,

$P((A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B))=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A^c\cap B)-P((A\cap B^c)\cap(A^c\cap B))=P(A\cap B^c)+P(A^c\cap B)$

Logically, $P(X\cap Y^c)=P(X)-P(X\cap Y)$ since it is the portion of $X$ that does not intersect with $Y$.

$$P(A\cap B^c)+P(A^c\cap B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
$$=P(A) + P(B) -2P(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

First we have
$$
(A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B)=A\bigtriangleup B= A\cup B-A\cap B
$$
where $A\bigtriangleup B$ is known as symmetric relation.

Also
$$
A\cap B\subset A\cup B \quad\text{and }\quad P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)
$$
 Thus
$$
P(A\cup B-A\cap B)=P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)
$$

Answer (score 0):

So we must prove:

$$P((A \cup B^c) \cap (A^c \cup B))=P(A) + P(B) -2P(A \cap B^c).$$

Let us try writing the set whose probability we are measuring on the LHS in simpler terms:

\begin{align*}
(A\cup B^C)\cap(A^C\cup B)={}&(A\cap A^C)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B^C\cap A^C)\cup(B^C\cap B)={} \\
{}={}&\varnothing\cup(A\cap B)\cup(A\cup B)^C\cup\varnothing.
\end{align*}

So the statement is evidently false: the set on the LHS is the whole set, hence the LHS is 1, whereas the RHS is not 1. Indeed, as @EricWozley mentioned in his comment, plugging in two empty sets returns a counterexample.

The point is you swapped all cups with caps and viceversa. So let us try rewriting the correct LHS set:

\begin{align*}
(A\cap B^C)\cup(A^C\cap B)={}&(A\cup A^C)\cap(A\cup B)\cap(B^C\cup A^C)\cap(B^C\cup B)={} \\
{}={}&X\cap(A\cup B)\cap(B^C\cup A^C)\cap X=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^C.
\end{align*}

Now since $A\cup B\supseteq A\cap B$, we can write that:

$$P((A\cap B^C)\cup(A^C\cap B))=P((A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^C)=P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B).$$

Since, in general, you have:

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B),$$

we are done. Just plug this into the equation just above it.

To follow the solution in the image, we note $A\cap B^C$ and $A^C\cap B$ are disjoint, and apply disjoint additivity, then $A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^C)$, and by using disjoint additivity on that we have:

$$P(A)=P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^C))=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^C).$$

The same can be done with $B$:

$$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A^C).$$

Solving the above for $P(A\cap B^C)$ and $P(A^C\cap B)$ and plugging into the expression $P(A\cap B^C)+P(B^C\cap A)$, we conclude, again.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $(A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B) \;\equiv\; (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$

Since $(A\cap B)\subseteq (A\cup B)$, then since probability is a $\sigma$-algebraic measure.
$$\mathsf P((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)) = \mathsf P(A\cup B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$$

The rest is just $(A\cup B) \equiv A \cup (B\setminus(A\cap B))$ so...